# The taphold event can't bind inside ScrollView

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, scrollview

I'm using PhoneGap and Jquery-mobile to develop for iPhone app.
My problem is I can't bind event taphold inside scrollView.

My app have struct like below:

HEADER:

```
<script src="javascripts/jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.3.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="javascripts/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="javascripts/jquery.mobile.scrollview.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="javascripts/scrollview.js"></script>
```

BODY:

```
<div data-role="content" data-theme= "d" data-scroll= "true" style= "overflow: scroll;">
<ul data-role="listview" data-theme="b">
    <li data-icon="thumb-up"><a href="#" class="list-item">
        <img src="http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/lists/images/album-ok.jpg"
        class = "ui-li-icon-small"></img>
        <div class="user_note">
            <p class="title-item">Broken Bells</p>
            <p class="detail-item">Broken Bells</p>
            <p class="time-past">5 minutes ago</p>
        </div>
        <p class="desc-item">this is descrition example test data this is descrition example test data </p>
    </a>
    </li>
...
</ul>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
    $(".grid-item, .list-item").unbind('taphold');
    $(".grid-item, .list-item").bind("taphold", 
              function(event, ui){
              var icons = $(this).parent().parent().find(".ui-icon-thumb-up");
              icons.load("thumb_x_icons.html");
    });
```

If I remove the ScrollView the event work for me.
Maybe the scrollView Prevent some events.

Is there any solution for this? or do you have any way to listening longPress event?

Comment: It has no error in console. but I trace into function taphold // also handles taphold
`$.event.special.tap = {
 setup: function() {
  var thisObject = this,
   $this = $( thisObject );

  $this.bind( "vmousedown", function( event ) {

   if ( event.which && event.which !== 1 ) {
    return false;
   }

   var origTarget = event.target,
    origEvent = event.originalEvent,
    timer;

   function clearTapTimer() {
    clearTimeout( timer );
   }`
And it never enter **vmousedown**

Comment: I edit the function in Jquery.Mobile and it works. Inside $.event.special.tap = function(){...} I edited **setTimeout** and change to use **delay** function. The function look like       $(this).delay(750, function(){
     triggerCustomEvent( thisObject, "taphold", $.Event( "taphold" ) );
      });

Comment: this might be a bug, I suggest you submit a bug/issue with jQM https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues

Comment: @user1140633 - do you know if this issue was ever resolved by the Jquery Mobile or Phonegap team? I couldn't find the issue on github. Cheers